# I have a problem to make an Http Call with data got by local storage

Tags: angular, api, ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic4

I make an API Request to get some data depends on the user Option.
I get this user option and store it in local storage to get it in API service to use it as a parameter in Url.
My Problem is these request work correctly in the first one only. when the user backward and select another option the service gets the old data from local storage, not the updated data. 
How I can solve this problem.

I try to clear local storage after call has done but it's not work

```
constructor(public http: HttpClient,public storage : Storage ) {

this.storage.get('cat').then((usercategory) => {
  this.usercategory =  usercategory;
  console.log(this.usercategory)
 });

 this.storage.get('loc').then((userlocation) => {
  this.userlocation =  userlocation;
  console.log(this.userlocation)

 });

 this.storage.get('serv').then((userservice) => {
  this.userservice =  userservice;
  console.log(this.userservice)

 });

getdata(){

return this.http.get(this.url + "&location=" + this.userlocation + 
"&price=" + this.usercategory + "&service=" + this.userservice);

}
```

Comment: Are you retrieving the data from local storage in a constructor?
please be more specific with 'request work for first one only'

Comment: yes, I retrieve data in the constructor.

Comment: I mean that the get request work fine when get values from local storage but when these values update and user make get request again the request work with old value

Comment: In that case, your properties are not updating. they only update when the service instantiates thats when your constructor gets called.

Comment: so where I must get local storage?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are updating the properties of the service class constructor and that's called only when the service instantiates.

You can make a function to get values and call that function whenever you are making an API call, in that way the properties will get updated every time you call the API.

**And remember to place only that code in constructor which needs to initialize the properties of the class or needs to get called only once during instantiation.**

```
constructor(public http: HttpClient,public storage : Storage ) {}

getlocalstorage(){

  this.storage.get('cat').then((usercategory) => {
  this.usercategory =  usercategory;
  console.log(this.usercategory)
 });

 this.storage.get('loc').then((userlocation) => {
  this.userlocation =  userlocation;
  console.log(this.userlocation)

 });

 this.storage.get('serv').then((userservice) => {
  this.userservice =  userservice;
  console.log(this.userservice)

 });
}


getdata(){
getlocalstorage();
return this.http.get(this.url + "&location=" + this.userlocation + 
"&price=" + this.usercategory + "&service=" + this.userservice);

}
```

Comment: I tried this solution but the values return undefined

Comment: Are you storing the values in local storage before fetching them?

Comment: can you send  the component code where you set the local storage

Answer (score 0):

I Solved the problem by Getting values from localStorage in the page component and pass it to API service.

```
             constructor(private AuthService: DubaiService, 
public loadingController: LoadingController,
public storage: Storage,
 private SettingsAuth :SettingsService,
 public modalController: ModalController) {

this.showLoader()


   Promise.all([this.storage.get("cat"),
   this.storage.get("loc"),
   this.storage.get("serv")]).t hen(values => {
  this.usercategory = values[0];
  this.userlocation = values[1];
  this.userservice = values[2];
  console.log(values)
  })
}


 ionViewDidEnter(){

this.AuthService.getListings(this.usercategory,this.userlocation,this.userservice)
 .subscribe((data) => {
  console.log(data);
  this.listing_items = data, 
  err => console.log(err);
  this.hideLoader()
  ,
  () =>  console.log("done");
   this.hideLoader();
   });



   }
```

and this My API Call method :

```
            getListings(usercategory,userlocation,userservice){

           return this.http.get(this.url + "&location=" + userlocation + 
           "&price=" + usercategory + "&service=" + userservice);

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Getting values from local storage is async. Therefore you need to await these values before you use them like:

```
constructor(public http: HttpClient,public storage : Storage ) {}

async getlocalstorage(){

  await this.storage.get('cat').then((usercategory) => {
  this.usercategory =  usercategory;
  console.log(this.usercategory)
 });

 await this.storage.get('loc').then((userlocation) => {
  this.userlocation =  userlocation;
  console.log(this.userlocation)

 });

 await this.storage.get('serv').then((userservice) => {
  this.userservice =  userservice;
  console.log(this.userservice)

 });
}
```